# How to pass authentication token in RSpec test for JSON API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec-rails

I'm trying to add an authorization token to an RSpec `get` JSON API test in Rails. But everything tried so far results in an error. The issue seems that the token is not being properly passed in the request.

```
expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 401
```

**Current code:**

Project_spec.rb (tests)

```
before do
    @project = create(:project, :key => "123")
    get '/api/v1/projects/1', {:Authorization => "Token 123"}, format: :json
end

it "returns correct status" do
    expect( response ).to have_http_status(:success)
end
```

ProjectsController.rb

```
before_filter :restrict_access, :except => :create

def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    render json: @project
end

def restrict_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
        Project.exists?(key: token)
    end
end
```

Based on a few recommended solution found online, I've tried

1. `get '/api/v1/projects/1', format: :json, token: "123"`
2. `get '/api/v1/projects/1', { 'HTTP-AUTHORIZATION' => 'Token "123"' }, format: :json`
3. `get '/api/v1/projects/1', {:Authorization => "Token 123"}, format: :json`

But nothing seems to successfully pass the authorization token.

Note: Style in #3 works when posting from an external application, but not in the RSpec test itself.

Does anyone have experience with this and can share some direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use it like:

```
 get '/api/v1/projects/1', {}, { Authorization:  "Token 123"}
```

`get` is the http method, `{}` an empty params,  `{ :Authorization =>  "Token 123"}` headers

> get(path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = nil)

[`Documentation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get)

Other way:

```
before do
    # some code here
    @request.env['Authorization'] = "Token 123"
    get '/api/v1/projects/1', format: :json
end
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty params?

Comment: If you omit it then `{ Authorization:  "Token 123"}` recognize as params and not a header.

Answer (score 6):

It worked when I just tried like this

```
get '/api/v1/projects/1', as: :json, headers: {:Authorization => "Token 123"}
```